# Hardware for Deep Learning

Tags: gpu, cpu, hardware

I have a couple questions on hardware for a Deep Learning project I'm starting, I intend to use pyTorch for Neural Networks.

I am thinking about going for an 8th Gen CPU on a z390 (I'll wait month to see if prices drop after 9th gen CPU's are available) so I still get a cheaper CPU that can be upgraded later.

Question 1) Are CPU cores going to be beneficial would getting the latest Intel chips be worth the extra cores, and if cores on CPU will be helpful, should I just go AMD?

I am also thinking about getting a 1080ti and then later on, once I'm more proficient adding two more 2080ti's, I would go for more but it's difficult to find a board to fit 4.

Question 2) Does mixing GPU's effect parallel processing, Should I just get a 2080ti now and then buy another 2 later. And a part b to this question do the lane speeds matter, should I spend more on a board that doesn't slow down the PCIe slots if you utilise more than one.

Question 3) More RAM? 32GB seems plenty. So 2x16gb sticks with a board that can has 4 slots up to 64gb.

Comment: Hardware-only questions are off-topic here. Nevertheless, if you are going to purchase an Intel CPU for a multi-GPU setup, you need a mobo-CPU combo with the maximum amount of PCIe lanes. Last time I checked, this meant buying a Xeon e5 or a Core chip for the same socket (those are higher-clocked non-ECC Xeons). You generally need around 2 cores per GPU. With 3 GPUs a hexa/octa-core Xeon will suffice. Those are not far too expensive. And if you really need 3 GPUs, then your work would likely require tons of RAM (at least 128GB), which  brings you into the entry-level server mobo market.

Comment: Apologies, I should have known, thanks for the response despite it being off topic, It's food for thought, I need to do a bit more research.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The matter when running multi GPU is also the number of available PCIe lanes. If you may go for up to 4 GPUs, I'd go for AMD Threadrippers for the 64 PCIe lanes.

For machine learning in a general manner, core & thread count is quite important, so TR is still a good option, depending on the budget of course.

Few poeple mention that running an instance on each GPU may be more interesting, if you do so, mising GPUs is not a problem.

32GB of ram seems good, no need to go for 4 sticks if your CPU does not support quad channel indeed.

Comment: Interesting, based on yours and Eli's comments. I need to completely re-think my current build. I'm glad I didn't drop £5k before asking.