# Is there a hardware benchmark for deep learning?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, pytorch, benchmarking, hardware

In this article from Tim Dettmers: [Full hardware guide for Deep Learning](https://timdettmers.com/2018/12/16/deep-learning-hardware-guide/),  he states that PCI lanes speed doesn't matter a lot for Deep Learning.

But on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52817053/hardware-for-deep-learning), the approved answer states that a CPU with the right amount of PCI lanes is required for Deep Learning. (according to me PCI lane speed and amount of PCI lanes managed by CPU are dependent)

So, I'm looking at a benchmark for Deel Learning to compare those theories/facts.

Looking at the existing benchmarks for Deep Learning, it seems that they are all only testing GPUs capacity, comparing one Graphic card to another, focusing on matrix multiplication.

I'm wondering if there is a benchmark that scores the sum of all hardware components required for deep learning (and especially the training phase): CPU, Memory, GPU, PCIe speed, hard drive, motherboard.

To list what I have tested:

- [DAWNBench/MLPerf](https://dawn.cs.stanford.edu/benchmark/) Define the specifications of a DL benchmark, whatever the platform and the framework. Their [code](https://github.com/mlperf) is partially incomplete.
- [AI Benchmark](http://ai-benchmark.com/) primarily focusing on mobile. Simple to use with [the code available](https://github.com/ai-benchmark) and a friendly scoring system. But even with a high precision parameter, the models are tested on small batches (I guess it's to keep it usable on mobile)
- [AI Matrix](https://github.com/alibaba/ai-matrix) from Alibaba: A very heavy and complete one but testing only the GPUs.
- [Lambda Labs Benchmark](https://github.com/lambdal/lambda-tensorflow-benchmark), I didn't get it working... non-available version of Tensorflow, non-compatible with recent Cuda versions..

(I know this is related to hardware, but as I'm looking for a software library, I post here!)

Comment: This is interesting, although I think it would be difficult to find a unique benchmark that gives a universal score. What I mean is there are many kinds of DL problems, if you work with images or video CPU-to-GPU latency will have a more important impact that if you work with, say, text data, and there are so many possible factors to consider, linear algebra, activation functions, RNNs... But if you focus in a more or less specific domain (e.g. image classification) it should be possible to have a reasonable benchmark for it...

Comment: @jdehesa Thanks. The benchmarks listed above cover different DL problems (RNN, CNN, LSTM, ...) AI Matrix automatically downloads more than 200Gb of various data (texts, images, videos). AI Benchmark makes a score for each problem and sums it at the end. As you say, I don't think that such a universal score exist, but any rating than allows to compare one computer config to another will do the job :)